# Is Xbox Kinect hardware compatible with OpenNI drivers and middleware?

Tags: kinect

I am currently exploring the difference between [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page)'s libfreenect and the [OpenNI SDK](http://www.openni.org). The latter seems to offer more features and options. But I currently only have the Xbox Kinect hardware device.

Can anyone tell me if the Xbox Kinect is compatible with OpenNI?

Comment: What operating system?  The problem you will face is the fact the current drivers for Windows does not support the XBOX Kinect nor do you want to actually use it since its technicaly inferier.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing that FAAST projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/faast/ (which uses the kinect to map actions to keypresses/mouseclicks) supported using either the Microsoft drivers or the OpenNI, and I got both to work using an Xbox Kinect (not Kinect for Windows), so this suggests that it is possible.